# Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?

Tags: rust, reference, covariance, lifetime

A few days ago, there was [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089410/lifetimes-and-references-to-objects-containing-references) where someone had a problem with linked lifetimes of a mutable reference to a type which contained borrowed data itself. The problem was supplying a reference to the type with a borrow of the same lifetime as the borrowed data inside the type.
I tried to recreate the problem:

```
struct VecRef<'a>(&'a Vec<u8>);

struct VecRefRef<'a>(&'a mut VecRef<'a>);

fn main() {
    let v = vec![8u8, 9, 10];
    let mut ref_v = VecRef(&v);
    create(&mut ref_v);
}

fn create<'b, 'a>(r: &'b mut VecRef<'a>) {
    VecRefRef(r);
}
```

[Example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e395fadea1b07fcb3874&version=nightly)

I explicitly annotated `'b` here in `create()`. This does not compile:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/main.rs:12:15
   |
11 | fn create<'b, 'a>(r: &'b mut VecRef<'a>) {
   |                      ------------------
   |                      |
   |                      these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
12 |     VecRefRef(r);
   |               ^ ...but data from `r` flows into `r` here
```

The lifetime `'b` is something like `'b < 'a` and therefore violating the constraint in the `VecRefRef<'a>` to be of exactly the same lifetime as the referred to `VecRef<'a>`.

I linked the lifetime of the mutable reference with the borrowed data inside the `VecRef<'a>`:

```
fn create<'a>(r: &'a mut VecRef<'a>) {
    VecRefRef(r);
}
```

Now it works. But why? How was I even able to supply such a reference? The mutable reference `r` inside `create()` has the lifetime of `VecRef<'a>` not `'a`. Why wasn't the problem pushed up to the calling side of the function `create()`?

I noticed another thing I did not understand. If I use an *immutable* reference inside the `VecRefRef<'a>` struct, it somehow does not matter any more when supplying a reference with a different lifetime of `'a`:

```
struct VecRef<'a>(&'a Vec<u8>);

struct VecRefRef<'a>(&'a VecRef<'a>); // now an immutable reference

fn main() {
    let v = vec![8u8, 9, 10];
    let mut ref_v = VecRef(&v);
    create(&mut ref_v);
}

fn create<'b, 'a>(r: &'b mut VecRef<'a>) {
    VecRefRef(r);
}
```

[Example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bdc017a87d1c7d77977e&version=nightly)

This works as opposed to the first example where `VecRefRef<'a>` took a mutable reference to a `VecRef<'a>`. I know that mutable references have different aliasing rules (no aliasing at all) but what has that to do with the linked lifetimes here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **Warning:** I'm speaking from a level of expertise that I don't really have. Given the length of this post, I'm probably wrong a large number of times.

> **TL;DR:** Lifetimes of top-level values are covariant. Lifetimes of referenced values are invariant.

#### Introducing the problem

You can simplify your example significantly, by replacing `VecRef<'a>` with `&'a mut T`.

Further, one should remove `main`, since it's more complete to talk about the *general* behaviour of a function than some particular lifetime instantiation.

Instead of `VecRefRef`'s constructor, let's use this function:

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}
```

Before we go further, it's important to understand how lifetimes get implicitly cast in Rust. When one assigns a pointer to another explicitly annotated name, lifetime coercion happens. The most obvious thing this allows is shrinking the lifetime of the top-level pointer. As such, this is not a typical move.

> **Aside:** I say "explicitly annotated" because [in implicit cases like `let x = y` or `fn f<T>(_: T) {}`, reborrowing doesn't seem to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154387/why-is-the-mutable-reference-not-moved-here/32158223#32158223). It is not clear whether this is intended.

The full example is then

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

which gives the same error:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/main.rs:5:26
  |
4 |     fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
  |                                       ------------------
  |                                       |
  |                                       these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
5 |         use_same_ref_ref(reference);
  |                          ^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `reference` flows into `reference` here
```

#### A trivial fix

One can fix it by doing

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a>(reference: &'a mut &'a mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

since the signatures are now logically the same. However, what is not obvious is why

```
let mut val = ();
let mut reference = &mut val;
let ref_ref = &mut reference;

use_ref_ref(ref_ref);
```

is able to produce an `&'a mut &'a mut ()`.

#### A less trivial fix

One can instead enforce `'a: 'b`

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a: 'b, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

This means that the lifetime of the outer reference is *at least* as large as the lifetime of the inner one.

It's not obvious

- why `&'a mut &'b mut ()` is not castable to `&'c mut &'c mut ()`, or
- whether this is better than `&'a mut &'a mut ()`.

I hope to answer these questions.

#### A non-fix

Asserting `'b: 'a` does not fix the problem.

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b: 'a>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

#### Another, more surprising fix

Making the outer reference immutable fixes the problem

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

#### And an even more surprising non-fix!

Making the *inner* reference immutable doesn't help at all!

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

## BUT WHY??!

And the reason is...

#### Hold on, first we cover variance

Two very important concepts in computer science are **covariance** and **contravariance**. I'm not going to use these names (I'll be very explicit about which way I'm casting things) but those names are still very useful for [searching the internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

It's very important to understand the concept of variance before you can understand the behaviour here. If you've taken a university course that covers this, or you can remember it from some other context, you're in a good position. You might still appreciate the help linking the idea to lifetimes, though.

#### The simple case - a normal pointer

Consider some stack positions with a pointer:

```
    ║ Name      │ Type                │ Value
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────────────┼───────
  1 ║ val       │ i32                 │ -1
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────────────┼───────
  2 ║ reference │ &'x mut i32         │ 0x1
```

The stack grows downwards, so the `reference` stack position was created after `val`, and will be removed before `val` is.

Consider that you do

```
let new_ref = reference;
```

to get

```
    ║ Name      │ Type        │ Value  
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────┼─────── 
  1 ║ val       │ i32         │ -1     
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────┼─────── 
  2 ║ reference │ &'x mut i32 │ 0x1    
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────┼─────── 
  3 ║ new_ref   │ &'y mut i32 │ 0x1
```

What lifetimes are valid for `'y`?

Consider the two mutable pointer operations:

- **Read**
- **Write**

**Read** prevents `'y` from growing, because a `'x` reference only guarantees the object stays alive during the scope of `'x`. However, **read** does not prevent `'y` from shrinking since any read when the pointed-to value is alive will result in a value independent of the lifetime `'y`.

**Write** prevents `'y` from growing also, since one cannot write to an invalidated pointer. However, **write** does not prevent `'y` from shrinking since any write to the pointer copies the value in, which leaves it independent of the lifetime `'y`.

#### The hard case - a pointer pointer

Consider some stack positions with a pointer pointer:

```
    ║ Name      │ Type                │ Value  
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  1 ║ val       │ i32                 │ -1     
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  2 ║ reference │ &'a mut i32         │ 0x1    
 ───╫───────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  3 ║ ref_ref   │ &'x mut &'a mut i32 │ 0x2
```

Consider that you do

```
let new_ref_ref = ref_ref;
```

to get

```
    ║ Name        │ Type                │ Value  
 ───╫─────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  1 ║ val         │ i32                 │ -1     
 ───╫─────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  2 ║ reference   │ &'a mut i32         │ 0x1    
 ───╫─────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  3 ║ ref_ref     │ &'x mut &'a mut i32 │ 0x2    
 ───╫─────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────── 
  4 ║ new_ref_ref │ &'y mut &'b mut i32 │ 0x2
```

Now there are two questions:

1. What lifetimes are valid for `'y`?
2. What lifetimes are valid for `'b`?

Let's first consider `'y` with the two mutable pointer operations:

- **Read**
- **Write**

**Read** prevents `'y` from growing, because a `'x` reference only guarantees the object stays alive during the scope of `'x`. However, **read** does not prevent `'y` from shrinking since any read when the pointed-to value is alive will result in a value independent of the lifetime `'y`.

**Write** prevents `'y` from growing also, since one cannot write to an invalidated pointer. However, **write** does not prevent `'y` from shrinking since any write to the pointer copies the value in, which leaves it independent of the lifetime `'y`.

This is the same as before.

#### Now, consider `'b` with the two mutable pointer operations

**Read** prevents `'b` from growing, since if one was to extract the inner pointer from the outer pointer you would be able to read it after `'a` has expired.

**Write** prevents `'b` from growing also, since if one was to extract the inner pointer from the outer pointer you would be able to write to it after `'a` has expired.

**Read** and **write** together also prevent `'b` from shrinking, because of this scenario:

```
let ref_ref: &'x mut &'a mut i32 = ...;

{
    // Has lifetime 'b, which is smaller than 'a
    let new_val: i32 = 123;

    // Shrink 'a to 'b
    let new_ref_ref: &'x mut &'b mut i32 = ref_ref;

    *new_ref_ref = &mut new_val;
}

// new_ref_ref is out of scope, so ref_ref is usable again
let ref_ref: &'a mut i32 = *ref_ref;
// Oops, we have an &'a mut i32 pointer to a dropped value!
```

**Ergo, `'b` cannot shrink and it cannot grow from `'a`, so `'a == 'b` exactly.** This means `&'y mut &'b mut i32` is invariant in the lifetime 'b.

#### OK, does this solve our questions?

Remember the code?

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

When you call `use_same_ref_ref`, a cast is attempted

```
&'a mut &'b mut ()  →  &'c mut &'c mut ()
```

Now note that `'b == 'c` because of our discussion about variance. Thus we are actually casting

```
&'a mut &'b mut ()  →  &'b mut &'b mut ()
```

The outer `&'a` can only be shrunk. In order to do this, the compiler needs to know

```
'a: 'b
```

The compiler does not know this, and so fails compilation.

#### What about our other examples?

The first was

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a>(reference: &'a mut &'a mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

Instead of `'a: 'b`, the compiler now needs `'a: 'a`, which is trivially true.

The second directly asserted `'a: 'b`

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a: 'b, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

The third asserted `'b: 'a`

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b: 'a>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

This does not work, because this is not the needed assertion.

#### What about immutability?

We had two cases here. The first was to make the outer reference immutable.

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

This one worked. Why?

Well, consider our problem with shrinking `&'b` from before:

> **Read** and **write** together also prevent `'b` from shrinking, because of this scenario:
>
> ```
> let ref_ref: &'x mut &'a mut i32 = ...;
>
> {
>     // Has lifetime 'b, which is smaller than 'a
>     let new_val: i32 = 123;
>
>     // Shrink 'a to 'b
>     let new_ref_ref: &'x mut &'b mut i32 = ref_ref;
>
>     *new_ref_ref = &mut new_val;
> }
>
> // new_ref_ref is out of scope, so ref_ref is usable again
> let ref_ref: &'a mut i32 = *ref_ref;
> // Oops, we have an &'a mut i32 pointer to a dropped value!
> ```
>
> **Ergo, `'b` cannot shrink and it cannot grow from `'a`, so `'a == 'b` exactly.**

This can only happen because we can swap the inner reference for some new, insufficiently long lived reference. If we are not able to swap the reference, this is not a problem. Thus shrinking the lifetime of the inner reference is possible.

#### And the failing one?

Making the inner reference immutable does not help:

```
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

This makes sense when you consider that the problem mentioned before never involves any reads from the inner reference. In fact, here's the problematic code modified to demonstrate that:

```
let ref_ref: &'x mut &'a i32 = ...;

{
    // Has lifetime 'b, which is smaller than 'a
    let new_val: i32 = 123;

    // Shrink 'a to 'b
    let new_ref_ref: &'x mut &'b i32 = ref_ref;

    *new_ref_ref = &new_val;
}

// new_ref_ref is out of scope, so ref_ref is usable again
let ref_ref: &'a i32 = *ref_ref;
// Oops, we have an &'a i32 pointer to a dropped value!
```

#### There was another question

It's been quite long, but think back to:

> One can instead enforce `'a: 'b`
>
> ```
> fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(reference: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}
>
> fn use_ref_ref<'a: 'b, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
>     use_same_ref_ref(reference);
> }
> ```
>
> This means that the lifetime of the outer reference is *at least* as large as the lifetime of the inner one.
>
> It's not obvious
>
> - why `&'a mut &'b mut ()` is not castable to `&'c mut &'c mut ()`, or
> - whether this is better than `&'a mut &'a mut ()`.
>
> I hope to answer these questions.

We've answered the first bullet-pointed question, but what about the second? Does `'a: 'b` permit more than `'a == 'b`?

Consider some caller with type `&'x mut &'y mut ()`. If `'x : 'y`, then it will be automatically cast to `&'y mut &'y mut ()`. Instead, if `'x == 'y`, then `'x : 'y` holds already! The difference is thus only important if you wish to return a type containing `'x` to the caller, who is the only one able to distinguish the two. Since this is not the case here, the two are equivalent.

#### One more thing

If you write

```
let mut val = ();
let mut reference = &mut val;
let ref_ref = &mut reference;

use_ref_ref(ref_ref);
```

where `use_ref_ref` is defined

```
fn use_ref_ref<'a: 'b, 'b>(reference: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(reference);
}
```

how is the code able to enforce `'a: 'b`? It looks on inspection like the opposite is true!

Well, remember that

```
let reference = &mut val;
```

is able to shrink its lifetime, since it's the outer lifetime at this point. Thus, it can refer to a lifetime *smaller* than the real lifetime of `val`, even when the pointer is outside of that lifetime!

Comment: *Read prevents `'b` from growing, since if one was to extract the inner pointer from the outer pointer you would be able to read it after `'a` has expired.* -- Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @soupybionics I suspect I was wrong about this. Let me get back to you.

Comment: @soupybionics Sorry, I seem to have lost track of your question. I remember looking into it and thinking I was wrong, but I can't remember the details. I will note that `&'static &'b` *can* be cast to `&'static &'static` which suggests you are right, but I don't think this is correct. Rather, there is probably an implicit assumption that `'b: 'a`; casting `&'a &'b` to `&'a &'static` fails.

Answer (score 7):

> The mutable reference `r` inside `create()` has the lifetime of `VecRef<'a>` not `'a`

This is a common source of confusion. Check this function definition:

```
fn identity<'a, T>(val: &'a T) -> &'a T { val }
```

In a function definition, `'a` is a *generic* lifetime parameter, which parallels a generic type parameter (`T`). When the function is called, the caller decides what the concrete values of `'a` and `T` will be. Let's look back at your `main`:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![8u8, 9, 10];   // 1 |-lifetime of `v`
    let mut ref_v = VecRef(&v); // 2 |  |-lifetime of `ref_v` 
    create(&mut ref_v);         // 3 |  |
}
```

`v` will live for the entire run of `main` (1-3), but `ref_v` only lives for the two final statements (2-3). Note that `ref_v` *refers to* a value that outlives it. If you then take a reference to `ref_v`, you have a reference to something that lives from (2-3) that itself has a reference to something that lives from (1-3).

Check out your fixed method:

```
fn create<'a>(r: &'a mut VecRef<'a>)
```

This says that *for this function call*, the reference to the `VecRef` and the reference it contains must be the same. There is a lifetime that can be picked that satisfies this — (2-3).

Note that your structure definition currently requires that the two lifetimes be the same. You could allow them to differ:

```
struct VecRefRef<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a mut VecRef<'b>);
fn create<'a, 'b>(r: &'a mut VecRef<'b>)
```

Note that you have to use the syntax `'b: 'a` to denote that the lifetime `'b` will outlive `'a`.

> If I use an immutable reference [...], it somehow does not matter any more

This I'm less sure about. I believe that what is happening is that because you have an immutable borrow, it's OK for the compiler to reborrow at a smaller scope for you automatically. This allows the lifetimes to match. As you pointed out, a mutable reference cannot have any aliases, even ones with a smaller scope, so the compiler can't help in that case.

Comment: I get it. Inside the body of the create function the picked lifetime will be the scope of 2-3, since from the set of supplied concrete lifetimes, it will be the only one that matches the constraint. As a result it will be the lifetime 'a of the created VecRefRef<'a>.

Comment: *Note that you have to use the syntax `'b : 'a` to denote that the lifetime `'a` will outlive `'b.`* — Shouldn't it be   "... denote that the lifetime `'b` will outlive `'a`." ?