# How can you resolve the need to mutably borrow in different match arms in Rust?

Tags: rust

When compiling this part of a [Piston](http://www.piston.rs/) game, I need to mutably borrow an object in different match arms. As far as I can tell, they should all go out of scope of each other, but yet a compile error is generated.

A simplified example that demonstrates the issue:

```
extern crate opengl_graphics;
extern crate piston_window;

use opengl_graphics::GlGraphics;
use opengl_graphics::glyph_cache::GlyphCache;
use piston_window::{Button, Context, Input, Key, OpenGL, PistonWindow, Size, text, WindowSettings};

struct Game<'a> {
    glyph_cache: &'a mut GlyphCache<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Game<'a> {
    pub fn new(glyph_cache: &'a mut GlyphCache<'a>) -> Self {
        Game { glyph_cache: glyph_cache }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut glyph_cache = GlyphCache::new("./FiraSans-Regular.ttf").unwrap();
    let opengl = OpenGL::V3_2;
    let mut window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new("Title",
                                                       Size {
                                                           width: 1024,
                                                           height: 768,
                                                       })
            .opengl(opengl)
            .build()
            .unwrap();
    let mut gl = GlGraphics::new(opengl);

    while let Some(event) = window.next() {
        match event {
            Input::Render(args) => {
                gl.draw(args.viewport(),
                        |context, graphics| draw(context, graphics, &mut glyph_cache));
            }

            Input::Press(Button::Keyboard(key)) => {
                match key {
                    Key::Space => {
                        Game::new(&mut glyph_cache);
                        // In real code, the `Game` instance is then used here,
                        // until going out of scope.
                    }
                    _ => {}
                }
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}

fn draw(context: Context, graphics: &mut GlGraphics, glyph_cache: &mut GlyphCache) {
    text([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
         72,
         "Hello, World!",
         glyph_cache,
         context.transform,
         graphics);
}
```

I would think that when `Game` goes out of scope and is dropped, it would no longer effect the borrow. The compile error generated from stable Rust 1.16.0:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `glyph_cache` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:35:25
   |
35 |                         |context, graphics| draw(context, graphics, &mut glyph_cache));
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                              ----------- borrow occurs due to use of `glyph_cache` in closure
   |                         |
   |                         second mutable borrow occurs here
...
41 |                         Game::new(&mut glyph_cache);
   |                                        ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
49 | }
   | - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `glyph_cache` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:41:40
   |
41 |                         Game::new(&mut glyph_cache);
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                        |
   |                                        second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                        first mutable borrow occurs here
...
49 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Give your wrapper struct two different lifetimes:

```
struct Game<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    glyph_cache: &'a mut GlyphCache<'b>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Game<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn new(glyph_cache: &'a mut GlyphCache<'b>) -> Self {
        Game { glyph_cache: glyph_cache }
    }
}
```

---

Through commenting out code, removing wrapping code, creating replacement structs, etc., your example can be further minimized:

```
struct GlyphCache<'a>(&'a str);
struct Game<'a>(&'a mut GlyphCache<'a>);

fn main() {
    let mut glyph_cache = GlyphCache("dummy");
    loop {
        if true {
            &mut glyph_cache;
        } else {
            Game(&mut glyph_cache);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then unroll the loop one time and play with inlining the conditionals to find the case the compiler is complaining about:

```
struct GlyphCache<'a>(&'a str);
struct Game<'a>(&'a mut GlyphCache<'a>);

fn main() {
    let mut glyph_cache = GlyphCache("dummy");

    Game(&mut glyph_cache);
    &mut glyph_cache;
}
```

Amusingly, [a related question was asked in the last few days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43011827/155423), and [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423) is relevant to this question as well. This **thoroughly** describes the cause, which ends up being lifetime variance (or the lack thereof, perhaps).

As I understand it (and I might not), there's two pieces combining:

1. When the outer and inner lifetimes are the same, there's the possibility that the `Game` constructor function might take ownership of a reference from the `GlyphCache`. This checking is only done at the function signature level; the body of the constructor is not checked for the usage in `main`
2. Lifetimes are currently lexical. That means that although the struct is dropped immediately, the borrow/re-borrow/transfer of a borrow that *might* have happened lasts longer, conflicting with the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Some of my explanation is a bit fuzzy, so hopefully more knowledgable people will chime in.