# Why is HashMap::get_mut more picky than HashMap::get regarding lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a `struct Foo<'a>` which is a wrapper around `&'a str` references. And I want to populate a `HashMap` with `Foo`s as keys. Here is a snippet of code ([open it in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4ead2fb232e56a00d2f048adcc0c643c&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    txt: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let a = "hello".to_string();
    let a2 = Foo { txt: &a };
    let b = "hello".to_string();
    let b2 = Foo { txt: &b };

    let mut hm = HashMap::<Foo, u32>::new();

    hm.insert(a2, 42);
    println!("=== {:?}", hm.get(&b2));     // prints Some(42)
    println!("=== {:?}", hm.get_mut(&b2)); // prints Some(42)

    {
        let c = "hello".to_string();
        let c2 = Foo { txt: &c };
        println!("=== {:?}", hm.get(&c2));         // prints Some(42)
        // println!("=== {:?}", hm.get_mut(&c2));  // does not compile. Why?
        // hm.insert(c2, 101);                     // does not compile, but I understand why.
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs  perfectly, but the compiler complains if I uncomment the two last lines of code. More precisely, it complains about the borrowed value in `c2` not living long enough.

For the last one (`insert`), this is perfectly understandable: I can not move `c2` into the `HashMap`, which lives longer than data borrowed by `c2` from `c`.

However, I don't understand why the second-to-last line (`get_mut`) has the same problem: in that case, the borrowed data should only be necessary during the call to `get_mut`, it is not moved into the `HashMap`.

This is all the more surprising that the `get` above works perfectly (as I expected), and that both `get` and `get_mut` have identical signatures when it comes to the `k` parameter...

---

After digging a little more,
I reproduced the problem with plain references (instead of a struct embedding a reference).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let a = 42;
    let b = 42;

    let mut hm = HashMap::<&u32,u32>::new();

    hm.insert(&a, 13);
    println!("=== {:?}", hm.get(&&b));     // prints Some(13)
    println!("=== {:?}", hm.get_mut(&&b)); // prints Some(13)

    {
        let c = 42;
        println!("=== {:?}", hm.get(&&c));        // prints Some(13)
        //println!("=== {:?}", hm.get_mut(&&c));  // does not compile. Why?
    } 
}
```

([open in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c6b3dcd61d6bcb4334e291fb8b9cff7c&version=undefined&mode=undefined))

Again, uncommenting the last line causes the compiler to complain (same message as above).

However, I found an interesting workaround for this particular example: replacing `&&c` by `&c` in the last line solves the problem -- actually, one can replace `&&` by `&` in all calls to `get` and `get_mut`. I guess this has to do with `&T` implementing `Borrow<T>`.

I don't understand precisely what, in this workaround, convinces the compiler to do what I want it to do. And I can not apply it directly to my original code, because I don't use *references* as keys, but objects embedding references, so I can not replace `&&` by `&`...

Comment: I believe this question to already be answered by [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain how this differs from the existing answers. Otherwise, we can mark this as already answered.

Comment: Additionally, how does *the compiler know* that `get_mut` isn't going to store the argument in the `HashMap`, using only the signature of the function?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that my question is the same as the one you referred to. Mostly, the difference is that in my case, only immutable references to `Foo` (the borrowing type) are involved.

Comment: However, you are spot on regarding `get_mut`: the difference (with `get`) is not about parameter `k`, but about `self` being mutable.

Comment: Right, it's the difference between `&self` and `&mut self`. Thanks to lifetime elision, the method is `get_mut<'a, Q: ?Sized>(&'a mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<&'a mut V>` — the lifetimes are linked.

Comment: Yes, but (my understanding of) lifetime elision does not explain everything here. To be even more precise, we have `get_mut<'a, 'b, Q: ?Sized>(&'a mut self, k: &'b Q) -> Option<&'a mut V>`. But here the "inner" lifetime of Q seems to be constrained by `'a`.

Comment: If the answer to your question contains the word "variance", you're gonna have a bad time. For would-be answerers, here are some facts I found illuminating: `&T` is variant in `T`, `&mut T` is invariant in `T`, and `HashMap<K, V>` is variant in `K`. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises because an immutable reference is variant over its (referenced) type whereas a mutable reference is invariant over its type.

A great read for understanding the concept is the [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

## HashMap: `get` versus `get_mut`

Shrinking further down, this is a simpler code reproducing the problem:

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::<&u32, u32>::new();    // --+ 'a
    let c = 42;                                    // |  --+ 'b
                                                   // |    |
    HashMap::<&u32, u32>::get(&mut hm, &&c);       // |    |
    // HashMap::<&u32, u32>::get_mut(&mut hm, &&c);// |    |
}                                                  // +    +
```

## The immutable case

Consider the signature of `HashMap::get`:

```
fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
    where K: Borrow<Q>, Q: Hash + Eq
```

In this case `&Q` is `&&'b u32` and `get`'s receiver is `&Self`.

The variant nature of immutable references implies that 
a `&HashMap<&'a u32, u32>` can be used where a `&HashMap<'b u32, u32>` is required.

Thanks to this rule, the compiler considers the original invocation:

```
HashMap::<&'a u32, u32>::get(&hm, &&'b c);
```

equivalent to:

```
HashMap::<&'b u32, u32>::get(&hm, &&'b c);
```

The compiler infers from the interface, and **only from the interface**, that the method implementation can not introduce leaks: compilation succeeds.

## The mutable case

Consider the signature of `HashMap::get_mut`:

```
fn get_mut<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<&mut V>
    where K: Borrow<Q>, Q: Hash + Eq
```

Also in this case `&Q` is `&&'b u32`, but `get_mut`'s receiver is `&mut Self`.

The invariant nature of mutable references implies that a `&mut HashMap<&'a u32, u32>` can not be used where a `&mut HashMap<&'b u32, u32>` is expected.

Thanks to this rule the compiler throws an error because by analyzing **only** the interface:

```
HashMap::<&'a 32, u32>::get_mut(&mut hm, &&'b c);
```

the compiler can not exclude, for example, that `get_mut` might store a key with lifetime `'b`.

Such a key can not outlive the `hm` HashMap: compilation fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clarifies a lot of things (also because I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165917/why-does-linking-lifetimes-matter-only-with-mutable-references) before, on @shepmaster's advice). That being said, this is a pity here, because we know (unlike the compiler) that `get_mut` will not leak the passed key in the `HashMap` :-/

Comment: Now it is right. Many thanks @trentcl for the correction!

Comment: I still don't get why replacing `&&c` by `&c` works, though... I understand why it works type-wise (`K=&u32` implements `Borrow<Q>` where `Q=u32`); but I don't understand why, all of a sudden, the compiler is satisfied with the lifetimes in that case...

Comment: [`&'a u32` implements `Borrow<u32>` for any lifetime `'a`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/borrow.rs.html#95-97), and [`&'a u32` implements `Borrow<&'a u32>` by the reflexive implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/borrow.rs.html#85-87), but `&'a u32` *doesn't* implement `Borrow<&'b u32>` even if `'a: 'b`. This is because traits, `Borrow` included, are always invariant over their parameters.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine This also means that if you're willing to create a newtype struct to put in your `HashMap`, you can write that missing blanket `impl` yourself and get (almost) the original example to compile: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=28abb8003a1e2f9460f01468b9feeb5a&version=stable&mode=debug). So your intuition is right: the restriction is overly conservative.

Comment: @trentcl  Darn, I had the idea of the FooKey, but for some reason could not get it working. I'll start afain from your code, thanks. Note that FooKey must also implement Hash and Eq, consistently with Foo, in order to respect the contract of HashMap...

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine If you pass `&c` it works because passing *values by reference* is safe and `&&c` does not work because passing *references by reference* is not safe. See [this](https://gist.github.com/attdona/52126d892a38f4c8d2593639c7579905) just to get the idea.