# How does the compiler handle borrows when there is a function involving mutable/immutable references as arguments with (nested) lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

```
fn func_vecmut<'a>(v: &'a mut Vec<&'a i32>, s: &'a String) {}

fn func_vecmut_fresh_lf<'a, 'b>(v: &'a mut Vec<&'a i32>, s: &'b String) {}

fn func_vec<'a>(v: &'a Vec<&'a i32>, s: &'a String) {}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![];
    {
        let s: String = String::from("abc");

        /* Note: Below, only one function call is active at a time, other two commented out */
        func_vecmut(&mut v, &s);          // Understandably, compiler fails this.
        func_vecmut_fresh_lf(&mut v, &s); // Understandably, compiler passes this i.e with fresh lifetime for String.
        func_vec(&v, &s);                 // Why does compiler pass this?
    }
}
```

In `func_vecmut` (as I understand it), the compiler sees that the lifetime of `String` is same as `Vec` and the elements (`i32`) that it holds. And since `v` lives longer (defined outside the block), it extends the borrow to `s` beyond the scope of the block (i.e afterlife for `s`) and hence the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:30
   |
13 |         func_vecmut(&mut v, &s);          // Understandably, compiler fails this.
   |                              ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
16 |     }
   |     - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
17 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

The issue can be solved by giving a fresh lifetime to the `String` argument (see `func_vecmut_fresh_lf`).

But then, why does the compilation not fail for `func_vec(&v, &s)`?  The only difference being `&mut Vec`. Is this something to do with the fact that immutable references are `Copy`, whereas mutable ones are not?  If it is, how? The function bodies are empty, what does the compiler infer here?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165917/why-does-linking-lifetimes-matter-only-with-mutable-references). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: *The function bodies are empty, what does the compiler infer here?* — The compiler does not infer anything when calling a function. It **only** uses the function signature. See [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423) for more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165917/why-does-linking-lifetimes-matter-only-with-mutable-references)