# Why does this Rust error message talk about data "flowing"?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Sometimes when writing a function with multiple input lifetimes, I encounter an error like:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/main.rs:4:27
  |
3 | fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(_ra: &'a Box<()>, _rb: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
  |                             -----------               ----------
  |                             |
  |                             these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
4 |     use_same_ref_ref(_ra, _rb);
  |                           ^^^ ...but data from `_ra` flows into `_rb` here
```

Note the phrasing: "...but **data from `_ra` flows into** `_rb` here". The code to produce that looks like:

```rust
fn use_same_ref_ref<'c>(_ra: &'c Box<()>, _rb: &'c mut &'c mut ()) {}

fn use_ref_ref<'a, 'b>(_ra: &'a Box<()>, _rb: &'a mut &'b mut ()) {
    use_same_ref_ref(_ra, _rb);
}

fn main() {
    let mut ra = Box::new(());
    let mut rb = &mut ();
    use_ref_ref(&mut ra, &mut rb);
}
```

The underlying reason for this error is explained extremely well in [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165917/why-does-linking-lifetimes-matter-only-with-mutable-references;) **I am not asking about the reason this is an error!** I would like to know why the error message talks about data "flowing" from one reference into another, and how to interpret that.

The first few times I read it I found it extremely confusing. It even occurs with a single reference (as per the linked question) which is even more confusing ("data from x flows into x" - well, sure it does, who cares?).

What is the link between the compiler's "flowing" explanation and the aliasing constraints being enforced here?

Comment: Sorry for maybe stating an even more obvious thing, but does this explain the terminology? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis

Comment: @VictorSergienko I will read it a few times and let you know!