# Lifetime problem with self on nested iterators "returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a"

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm trying to write a trait which receives an `Iter<Item = T>` of work items, filters and then applies anything outstanding, and records the results. The trait contains some state (a connection to an external service). Because the definition of the methods is part of a trait, the return types are variations on `Box<dyn Iter<Item = (Status, Work)>` as a concession to the inability to use `-> impl Iterator` in traits yet.

I eliminated the `trait DoesWork` to keep the code simple, but assume the entire `impl OneKindOfRunner` is `impl DoesWork for OneKindOfRunner`, please ([in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab65c5247c45bb2da4587646c0d4b8c2)):

```
struct OneKindOfRunner {
    // conn: in reality this conn is mutable, and causes to need mut refs
    // to the OneKindOfRunner. The WorkRunner keeps a state, and that is
    // in a database backed by this conn, so work, filter and do_one_work
    // all need to communicate with the database (hence self)
    //
    // I don't know if I can reasonably implement Copy()
    // as E0505 suggests, I prefer not right now.
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Work {
    // some static stuff, no mutable state, really.
}

type WorkStatus = (bool, Work); // does the work need to happen?
type WorkResult = (bool, Work); // did we do the work successfully?

// In the real app, OneKindOfRunner implements a Runner
// trait, hence the Box<>ed dyn return types.
impl OneKindOfRunner {
    fn new() -> Self {
        OneKindOfRunner {}
    }

    fn do_one_work<'a>(&'a mut self, work_item: Work) -> WorkResult {
        (true, work_item) // return tuple indicating success or not (distinct from Result<T,E>)
    }

    fn filter_pending_work<'a>(
        &'a mut self,
        work: impl Iterator<Item = Work> + 'a,
    ) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = WorkResult> + 'a> {
        Box::new(work.map(|w| (false, w)).into_iter())
    }

    fn work<'a>(
        &'a mut self,
        work: impl Iterator<Item = Work> + 'a,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = WorkResult> + 'a>, ()> {
        Ok(Box::new(
            self.filter_pending_work(work)
                .map(move |(_status, work)| self.do_one_work(work))
                .into_iter(),
        ))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let work = vec![Work {}, Work {}, Work {}, Work {}].into_iter();
    let mut runner = OneKindOfRunner::new();

    match runner.work(work) {
        Ok(results) => {
            for (success, work) in results {
                println!("Result was {} for work {:?}", success, work)
            }
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("something err'd"),
    };
}
```

The code errs with the following:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `self` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:43:22
   |
37 |       fn work<'a>(
   |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
41 | /         Ok(Box::new(
42 | |             self.filter_pending_work(work)
   | |             ---- borrow of `*self` occurs here
43 | |                 .map(move |(_status, work)| self.do_one_work(work))
   | |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---- move occurs due to use in closure
   | |                      |
   | |                      move out of `self` occurs here
44 | |                 .into_iter(),
45 | |         ))
   | |__________- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
```

With or without the `move` on #43, I cannot find a way to make this work.

I thought the `&'a mut self`, and the `Result<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = WorkResult> + 'a>, ()>`  would ensure that the lifetimes of the result (which implies a dependency on the iterator closure?) are tied to the longevity of `self` (e.g I must consume the iterator before allowing the `self` to go out of scope, whoever is calling my `work()` function)

I believe the problem is stemming from using `self.<some fn>` twice (nested) which I don't know a good alternative for.

In reality we don't want to consume the `Iter<Item = Work>`, and to be able to cleanly `map()` over it once.

```
fn work<'a>(
    &'a mut self,
    work: impl Iterator<Item = Work> + 'a,
) -> Result<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = WorkResult> + 'a>, ()> {
    Ok(Box::new(
        self.filter_pending_work(work)
            .map(move |(_status, work)| self.do_one_work(work))
            .into_iter(),
    ))
}
```

Assigning the result of `self.filter_pending_work(work)` outside the box doesn't help, removing the `move (_status, work)` leads to some variation on:

```
44 | |                 .map(|(_status, work)| self.do_one_work(work))
   | |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---- second borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   | |                      |
   | |                      closure construction occurs here
45 | |                 .into_iter(),
46 | |         ))
   | |__________- returning this value requires that `*self` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Is there any reasonable way around this? Are `Iterator`s the right thing to do here, or should I just scrap the whole idea and work with a `Box<Vec<Work>>`? It feels like `Iterator<Item = Foo>` is the *more correct* thing to use because of Rust's strong APIs for filtering and mapping, but trying to *work* with iterators (rather than just use `into_iter()` on a `Vec<T>` is really quite painful.

Comment: I do mean in traits, which is why I mentioned a text that in the _real_ code, this is a trait, and that I cut 30 lines of boilerplate for the question by leaving it out, which, without the knowledge that it's usually a trait, makes the signatures look weird. Thanks for seeking clarification.

Comment: The usage of `&'a mut self` is about the worst thing here. See [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423)

Comment: The playground example can be made to compile by removing the `'a` on line 31. Does that solve your real problem?

Comment: Thanks trentcl, indeed it doesn't unfortunately. I thought the reproduction case was quite similar, but I must have been mistaken.